# How to model a 'history' table from a join table

Tags: data-modeling

I have a need to track some history for a table that contains ids from other tables:

[image]

I want to track the status of the company_device table such that I can make entries to know when the status of the relationship changed (when a device was assigned to a company, and when it was unassigned, etc). The company_device table would only contain current, existing relationships. So I'd like to do 'something' like this:

[image]

But this won't work, because it requires there to be a record in company_device for the FK to be satisfied in the company_device_history table. For example, if I

```
insert into company_device values (1,1);
insert into company_device_history values (1,1,'Assigned',now());
```

Then I can't ever remove the record from company_device because of the foreign key constraint. So I've currently settled on this:

[image]

so I'm not restricted by the foreign key.

My question is : is there a better way to model this? I could add the status and effective_date to the company_device table and query based on status or effective_date, but that doesn't seem to be a good solution to me. I'd like to know how others might approach this.

Comment: that's fine. foreign key is unwanted as record wouldn't exist in company_device if you deleted it and copied it to company_device_history. Another option is a db that supports SQL:2011 Temporal , such as DB2

Answer (score 0):

When looking exclusively at the *problem* (that is, when modeling the nature of the *business problem* at hand), the only thing you need is one single table COMPANY_DEVICE_ASSIGNMENT with four columns C_ID, D_ID, FROM and TO, telling you that "device D_ID was assigned to company C_ID from FROM to TO".

Systems do exist that allow you to work on this basis, however none of them speak SQL (an excellent book with an in-depth treatment of the subject matter of temporal data, I'd even call it the "canonical" work, is "Time and Relational Theory - Googling for it can't miss).  If you do this in an SQL system, this "straightforward" approach is not going to get you very far.  In that case, your practical options are limited by :

- what temporal features are offered by the DBMS you want/can/must use
- what features are supported by whatever modeling tool you want/can/must use to generate DDL.

As Neil's comment stated : the most recent version of the SQL standard had "temporal support" as its main novelty, and they are absolutely relevant to your problem, but the products actually offering these features are relatively few and far between.